# How to generate a matrix through a loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I´m wondering how to get these in Matlab:

```
a = 
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 6
5 7
6 8
7 9
8 10
9 11
10 12
```

Really the structure I want to do has 2 thousand files. but I will start with something easier.
So I was thinking about to do it throught a loop:

```
for i=1:1:10
a(i) = [i i+2]
end
```

but this give an error:

```
???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
I must be the same.
```

The idea is to generate a entire matrix (or structure, I suppose both are the same...) using a for loop (or may be there is a way to do it without any case of loop...).
Does anyone could tell me how to do it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please, could anyone give a piece of code to perform the first example I`ve written (a 2x10 matrix). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you are assigning two numbers to one element of your array a. Try

```
for i=1:1:10
  a(i,:) = [i i+2];
end
```

instead. Or, just use

```
a=[(1:10)' (3:12)'];
```

which replaces your loop...

Answer (score 0):

The specific matrix, **w/o loops**, where *n* is no. of rows:

```
n=10;
a=(1:n)';
m=[a  a+2];
```